# Overriding just the thumb style on a Slider element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a simple way to override the appearance of the `Thumb` on a `Slider` element without defining a whole custom `Slider` style? I want to use the default `Slider`, but just change the shape of the thumb to a circle. The questions I've seen so far tend to recommend defining a whole custom `Slider` element, but what I'm looking for is a way to override *just* the thumb without touching the other parts of the style - it seems like there should be some way to do this in a very small number of lines in the xaml file.

Comment: From what I've read the only way to do this is to export the style and then use it in your project with the appropriate elements changed. I don't think you can use `BasedOn` unless you have the style defined in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is. With a little hack. After the style is applied (in OnApplyTemplate() for example), you can do a FindName, ie:

```
Thumb thumb = Template.FindName("Thumb", this) as Thumb;
```

then replace the control template:

```
thumb.Template = ...;
```

You can't just put a style in your resource section that targets Thumbs because the default style gets overridden in the Slider style, but this is a nice work-around so you don't need to redefine the whole style. You can also put some logic in your thumb.Template line to pick a different template if you're vertical or horizontal or on the OS, etc.

Comment: This is good as a workaround, but it sounds like you're saying there's no way to implement this feature in the way that I would like - just putting a short `Thumb` override. Am I correct in this interpretation?

Comment: @ChrisH. I had a few other ideas (XAML only), but I tried them out real quick and they didn't work. If you dump out the entire style in Blend, you'll see they explicitly override the Thumb style. They do it that way because there are left, right, top and bottom thumbs. There isn't a built in way to do it.

Comment: @ChrisH. Btw, just to be clear, I wasn't suggesting you build the template in code, I was suggesting you define the template as you normally would in an override, but only force it in the code. Since the usual override techniques won't work in this case.